# Destroy PHP sessions by downtime

Tags: php

When you access the system, it generates a session as below:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Logged'] = time();
$_SESSION['Limit'] = 900; // 15 minutes
```

And when it exits the system, the session is destroyed.
The problem is when the user leaves the system without clicking the exit link and yes directly through the browser. How do I destroy the session by downtime? I tried the code below, but how do I know it's no longer in the system? It is necessary to change the status of the database and closing the system by the browser, I can not change.

```
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['Logged'])
    {
      $seconds = time()- $_SESSION['Logged'];
    }
    if($seconds > $_SESSION['Limit'])
    {
     mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE table_admin SET StatusAdmin = 0 WHERE IdUser = '".$id."';");
     session_destroy();
    }
```

I'm sorry about my English.

Comment: "I tried the code below, but how do I know it's no longer in the system?" Do you not trust `session_destroy()` to work as documented? Add some logging to ensure that if block is being hit like you expect and trust documented tools that you've chosen to use.

Comment: Hi Brandon. I'm sorry about my English. When the user clicks the exit button of the system, the session is destroyed, but when the user leaves the system closing the browser, the session it is destroyed, but I need to change the user's status in the database and thus I am not getting it. I made a change to my post.

Comment: It is necessary to change the status of the database and closing the system by the browser, I can not change.

Comment: do you log some kind of activity in the backend too? maybe you could use that as basis of inactivity. if last activity is done x number of minutes after now, then set as inactive. you'd probably need to run this task on background though to check. you could probably use websockets, but that's much of an overhead to just simply try to check for inactivity

Comment: You really don't need to do this in code. PHP already has it built in. All you gotta do is set the `session.gc_maxlifetime` to `900` either in your php.ini or by calling [`session.start()`](https://www.php.net/session-start) with the `$options` array set. Such as `session_start(["gc_maxlifetime" => 900])` the default value is 1440 by the way.

Comment: If you need to update the database when the session expires this needs to be handled outside of PHP sessions (would be my guess), I don't have a ton of experience working with PHP sessions but you'd need to have your session lifetimes tracked in a database and you'd need to have a background job running to check on those sessions and updating the database when they expire. PHP code can check the DB for active sessions to prevent reauthenticating or what-have-you but from what you need and what I know you can't do it this way you need more pieces involved.